# What is this horror RPG involves being chased by a monster, and uses cards or coins to decide what happens?

Tags: monsters, product-identification, playing-cards

I remember reading about an RPG that sounded really interesting. The details I remember are:

- You are being chased by a monster
- Encounters with the monster are uncommon
- It is a horror theme
- There are not a lot of rules, especially with describing the monster
- The monster was very hard to hurt, you wanted to escape it, not fight
- I think there was a storm or something that followed and hid the monster
- It may have involved cards or coins to decide what happens.
- It had very short rules.

It was definitely new, within the last decade. I can't remember exactly where I found it, but I know it was a PDF online.

I have been doing some googling, and its sounds very similar games like Trophy Dark, Kingdom Death, etc. It has no models through.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Here’s hoping someone can help you. You’ve done a pretty good job of listing what you can remember of the game itself, but it would probably help if you have any idea how old it might have been - was it published in the last decade? Also the context in which you encountered would be helpful, too; where did you read about it? Was it being discussed on a forum, and if so, which one?

Comment: It was definitely new, within the last decade. I can't remember exactly where I found it, but I know it was a pdf online. I have been doing some googling, and its sounds very similar games like Trophy Dark, Kingdom Death, etc. It has no models through.

Comment: those are all good details to add into the question!

Answer (score 3):

This is the game I was thinking of: [Gun&Slinger](https://forktwenty.itch.io/gun-and-slinger) by Nevyn Holmes.

Comment: Hello. While this may be the game OP is looking for, it would make a much better answer if you would describe *how* it fits all the points in the description. As it is now, it'll become worthless if the link goes down.

Comment: @Jithandix, since this definitely answers your own question of what game you were looking for, you can also click the green accept checkmark.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin Self answers can’t be accepted until the question is 48 hours old.

Comment: As @Mołot said, you should edit your answer to include the relevant details from *Gun&Slinger* that match the details you included in the question. (And if certain details don't match, that's probably worth mentioning as well.)